# Firebase Realtime Database Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have gotten this error a few times in the recent days and cannot identify what child() is getting a null string passed to it seeing as they are both hard-coded...

Has anyone else experienced this recently?

Thanks,
Keith

```
private void setupReports() {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("data").child("reports").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            availableReports.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ReportTitle report = new ReportTitle();
                report.setkey(ds.getKey());
                report.settitle(ds.getValue(String.class));
                availableReports.add(report);
            }

            //Sort alphabetically
            Collections.sort(availableReports, (o1, o2) -> o1.gettitle().compareTo(o2.gettitle()));

            //Show the available reports in the view
            updateUI();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(DatabaseReference.java:96) at ...Core.OverviewPage.setupReport(OverviewPage.java:253) at ...Core.OverviewPage.updateUI(OverviewPage.java:225) at ..Core.OverviewPage.access$000(OverviewPage.java:113) at ...Core.OverviewPage$1.onDataChange(OverviewPage.java:210)

Comment: i think problem is in this line ```FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()``` , make a variable that reference to `root` node then add listener on that reference.

Comment: like this ```private DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();```

Comment: Can you add your database structure?

Comment: There is no way the code you shared should be throwing the error you have in the title. Please find the exact error message *and stack trace* in your logcat output, and edit your question to include those.

Comment: Please don't put crash logs and code in comments - it's very hard to read. *update your question* with that type of information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67449449/4828650